# Who knows the architecture of Apple's AppStore

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I want to develop a app like AppStore on android, who knows how many parts should i focus on?
Such as the data structure of DataBase, server API, UI, and so on...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of android this is pretty simple since you just need to provide download links for the .apk-files. In order to achieve good download rates you can use Amazon S3 cloud or most other BLOB storage clouds like MS Azure.

As for the database you have several options: If you think you will have a lot of users and need to scale, you should go for a NoSQL-Database. On the way to chose which NoSQL-database to use, you have to think about which information you want to store. The Apple AppStore tracks a lot of your clicks and logs them, if you want to do a lot of logging, too then you should probably use cassandra. The main drawback of cassandra is that it is much more complicated to develop than a normal mySQL database or document databases like MongoDB. For rapid development but still having enough scalability I would suggest using MongoDB and maybe logging with another service like Google Analytics!

The main focus should be on UI then security and then on server performance. I suggest this order since if you don't have a nice UI, you won't have any users and the other components will most likely be irrelevant. If you have some users you should make sure that you don't get hacked and send out any viruses. This will kill your reputation and again you won't have any users. And if then at some point you have a lot of users you can optimise your server performance, since you need to scale.

For the above reasons, I would use nodejs, python django or PHP running on the HHVM on the server side. These allow for fast development on the server side and allow you to focus on your front end!

You also have to take into account that usually app stores are not only used via an app but also via the website. Therefore you have to allocate some resources for that, too.

I don't want to disappoint you but judging from your question, I am not sure whether you are up for this huge task! I certainly am not.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! You are so experienced. I'm just curious about AppStore these days, so i think if i began to develop this app, which parts should i focus on.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that was a question, but to make sure: UI and security are the most important ones at the beginning. (You should of course plan at least a little ahead so you don't run into drastic problems later if you are succesful! )